# CA2012 warning on using ValueTask in Blazor. How to implement "fire and forget" correctly in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, blazor

`IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync()` called as last thing in a code path causes CA2012 (Use ValueTasks correctly) warning. Can it be safely ignored, or should I fix that with awaiting it?

When I add `.Preserve()` at the end of my synchronous call the warning disappears, the code works the same. Why is that? What happens? What does this method do? The documentation (of `Preserve()` method) is unclear.

I want "fire and forget" use of a method that returns a `ValueTask`. What is the most correct way to achieve that, calling it from a synchronous method?

To add some context - I execute JS from my Blazor code. I do not rely on effects caused by the JS code after calling it. That's why I do not await it. I can refactor my code to await the `ValueTask` but would it serve any other purpose than making the Code Analyzer happy?

Comment: Many questions in a single question, it could be flagged as too broad, you may want to edit it and narrow it a bit. Regarding the CA2012 one, looks to me that the [CA2012 rule description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2012) is kinda clear.

Comment: I understand the rule, what I don't understand is `Preserve()` documentation. And what is the best way to fix the rule violation. I fixed it with "async all the way" approach, but I left the question to make sure if I made it the optimal way.

Comment: @Cleptus I edited the question. Do you think it's clearer and less broad now?

Comment: Indeed, probably you will get now more focused answers

Comment: All Preserve is doing in your case is hoodwinking the static analysis. What it does is return the `CompletedTask` as a new `ValueTask` or wraps the initial `Task` or `IValueTaskSource`. None of which make any sense in your situation. As to do what is the best practice, its use async all the way. or don't its up to you.

Comment: @Harry - A bit of code as to how you are using `IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync()` might help clarify why you are getting the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what about calling from old school event handlers? They can be at best `async void`

Blazor eventhandlers went back to school and can all be `async Task`. The Razor engine knows how to deal with that.

The only problem is with non-Blazor events, like the Elapsed event from a Timer. You may need `async void` there.

> For now my idea is to try to go "async all the way"

Yes, that is the way to go.

Going sync (non async) is a small optimization for code-paths that don't need anything async. For example the IncrementCount() method (eventhandler) in the Counter example.

> but would it serve any other purpose than making the Code Analyzer happy?

It would help Blazor to refresh the UI after your update is complete. A fire-and-forget has to do its own StateHasChanged() logic for one.

If you really want to f&f, `_ = DoSomethingAsyncWithoutAwait();`

`InvokeAsync()` sends your Task to the main UI thread. Currently that only applies to Blazor Server. It is only required when the Task needs to update the UI and from normal Blazor code it is then better to just await. The normal Blazor lifecycle will not be blocked.  Using it to avoid a warning is sub-optimal.

Comment: "InvokeAsync() sends your Task to the main UI thread" No, it does not send any Task object. It simply executes a given method on the associated renderer's
synchronization context. "Currently that only applies to Blazor Server" Do you mean this InvokeAsync(() => MethodNameAsync()) ; won't work on WebAssembly ? "It is only required when the Task needs to update the UI" The Task object Does Not Update the UI. It contains the result of an async action. "and from normal Blazor code it is then better to just await."

Comment: No, it is not better... It it the only way the calling code know that the awaited async method completed.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was aware of the last part, that the code must be awaited for the other code that depends on the results or side effects could work properly. But awaiting even at the end of the chain is better because it won't blow anything up when I change the code and add something later so my f&f would happen to be "not the last in the chain" anymore.